# Two finger swipe for Horizontal pager in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to implement two finger like swipe for HorizontalPager.  I understand the single swipe feature of HorizontalPager which works fine.  How to distinguish between a one finger swipe and two finger swipe?  Can anyone tell me how to implement two finger swipe for HorizontalPager?  A code sample would be more helpful.

Comment: two finger swipe? what does it mean?

Comment: It means that instead of swiping with one finger, you use two fingers simultaneously to swipe

Comment: what you want is to implement multitouch?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7840953/1026620

It should work if you override onTouchEvent in the View. With

```
event.getPointerCount()
```

check if it is equal to 2. In that case, change to the next page. Otherwise, ignore the gesture.