# How we can check how many fingers tap on the screen in java?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, multi-touch, motionevent, taps

What I'm trying to do is, When i click on the application screen I want to get how many Fingers tap on the screen ? Means 1 finger tap, 2 finger tap and three finger tap.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7840953/7746134

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268426/android-difference-between-action-up-and-action-pointer-up/4269592#4269592

Answer (score 0):

Use `MotionEvent.getPointerCount()`. You can read more details here: [Respond to touch events](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch)

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            int count = event.getPointerCount();
            // TODO: Do something you want here
            break;
    }
}
```