# Handling 3 finger tap in Android

Tags: android, touchscreen

I am using OnTouchListener to capture multitouch events for ex. a 3 finger tap , I could able to detect up to 2 fingers. i.e `event.getPointerCount()` returns upto 2.
Even same with `onTouchEvent()`. Is there any other API for handling this ?
I have enabled 3 finger tap detection on my test device.
getPointerCount() works in Motorola Droid with Android 4.1.2 but not in HTC One V with Android 4.0.3
[This](https://gist.github.com/raveebhat/6621262) is what I have done so far:

```
package com.example.toucheventsample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class TouchEventActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    videoView.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.touch_event, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean handleTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean handled = true;
    int action = event.getAction();
    int count = event.getPointerCount();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            if (3 == count) {
                // handle 3 finger tap
            }
            break;
    }
    return handled;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    int count = event.getPointerCount();
    handleTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: try looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893336/android-3-finger-touch-detection)

Comment: already seen. doesn't help